# MongoException: An equivalent index already exists with a different name and options

Tags: mongodb, yii2

Mongodb version: 6.0.3 
Yii2 version: 2.0.34

Debug_log:

```
MongoDB\Driver\Exception\CommandException: An equivalent index already exists with a different name and options. Requested index: { v: 2, key: { _fts: "text", _ftsx: 1 }, name: "full.eng_text", weights: { full.eng: 1 }, default_language: "english", language_override: "language", textIndexVersion: 3 }, existing index: { v: 2, key: { _fts: "text", _ftsx: 1 }, name: "full.uk_text", weights: { full.uk: 1 }, default_language: "english", language_override: "language", textIndexVersion: 3 } in /www/wwwroot/jumbotwo.space/public_shtml/YII/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb/src/Command.php:186
Stack trace:
#0 /www/wwwroot/jumbotwo.space/public_shtml/YII/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb/src/Command.php(186): MongoDB\Driver\Manager->executeCommand()
#1 /www/wwwroot/jumbotwo.space/public_shtml/YII/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb/src/Command.php(357): yii\mongodb\Command->execute()
#2 /www/wwwroot/jumbotwo.space/public_shtml/YII/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb/src/Collection.php(153): yii\mongodb\Command->createIndexes()
#3 /www/wwwroot/jumbotwo.space/public_shtml/YII/components/GoogleMapsApi.php(62): yii\mongodb\Collection->createIndex()
#4 /www/wwwroot/jumbotwo.space/public_shtml/YII/components/GoogleMapsApi.php(46): app\components\GoogleMapsApi->createDBs()
#5 /www/wwwroot/jumbotwo.space/public_shtml/YII/components/GoogleMapsApiGeocode.php(23): app\components\GoogleMapsApi->__construct()
#6 /www/wwwroot/jumbotwo.space/public_shtml/YII/controllers/AjaxController.php(36): app\components\GoogleMapsApiGeocode->__construct()
#7 [internal function]: app\controllers\AjaxController->actionSearch()
#8 /www/wwwroot/jumbotwo.space/public_shtml/YII/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array()
#9 /www/wwwroot/jumbotwo.space/public_shtml/YII/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(157): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams()
#10 /www/wwwroot/jumbotwo.space/public_shtml/YII/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): yii\base\Controller->runAction()
#11 /www/wwwroot/jumbotwo.space/public_shtml/YII/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(103): yii\base\Module->runAction()
#12 /www/wwwroot/jumbotwo.space/public_shtml/YII/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): yii\web\Application->handleRequest()
#13 /www/wwwroot/jumbotwo.space/public_shtml/index.php(14): yii\base\Application->run()
#14 {main}
```

Function works when the site language is main(uk), `response code 200` but gets error when language is english (en), `response code 500`.

I think that the problem is with `$collection->createIndex()` function on existing index. 
But idk

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a text index on a collection that already has one.

From the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-text/#create-text-index):

> A collection can have at most one text index.